# Design for an Asset Management System

Tags: database-design

I'm attempting to design a database to track IT Fixed Assets and Consumable Parts; what is the best practice for this?

Should I design separate tables for `Fixed Assets` and `Consumables`, or should I have just one table containing rows for both types of items, with a `Category` field?

Answer (score 1):

If the Fixed Assets and Consumables have some identical columns, they can be in one table. Then create a category like table.